# What is in the stack?

Tags: nvidia, raytracing, optix

I'm trying to understand what is stored in the stack in optix.

As I understand it, we set the stack size per context, and one stack is attached to each thread in the ray generation program.
When a ray is launched, the thread carries with it the stack, which stores the ray's payload.

I thought that, when we do a recursive ray-tracer for example, the stack overflow would occur because there would be too many payloads to keep in the memory. But right now, I have a program with a radiance ray that has a payload of float + 3 uint, and a shadow ray with only a float, and there is only one bounce. However, my stack needs to be bigger that 1024 to avoid a stack overflow. Surely, this is way more that just my two payloads.

So I wonder, what else is in the stack?
(I mean in general, not in my particular case. What is stored in the stack except the ray(s) payload(s) (if they are)? For example, do we also store information about the hits? about the scene tree? Do we keep track of which program called the current ray?)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on the NVIDIA board [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/881722/?comment=4684311)

> Detlef Roettger wrote
>
> "The stack is also used to save and restore live variables around
>   function calls (e.g. rtTrace or callable programs). That's the
>   background for one of the performance advice in the OptiX Programming
>   Guide which starts with *Try to minimize live state across calls to
>   rtTrace in programs.*"

More info on this at §3.1.3 - Global State in the [OptiX Programming guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/optix-documentation).

Remember that OptiX programs are full blown CUDA kernels combined together. Stack memory is therefore also used for ordinary execution needs (the amount is likely to vary even between CUDA versions).